# URL Route Parameters in AngularJS ui-router

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I want to be able to reload just the nested view of my application and attached a route parameter on so that I can have URL routing in my application.  I cannot figure out how to do this, I initially had it working with a query like this:

```
$location.search('userId', user._id);
//http://localhost:9000/#/user/?userId=123456789
```

My desired URL is below, with the `userId = 123456789`

```
http://localhost:9000/#/user/123456789
```

My app.js file

```
$stateProvider
    .state('index', {
        url: '/',
        views: {
            '@' : {
                templateUrl: 'views/layout.html'
            },
            'top@index' : {
                templateUrl: 'views/top.html',
                controller: function($scope, $state) {
                    $scope.userLogOut = function() {
                        $state.go('login');
                    };
                }
            },
            'left@index' : { templateUrl: 'views/left.html' },
            'main@index' : { templateUrl: 'views/main.html' }
        }
    })
    .state('index.user', {
        url: 'user:userId',
        templateUrl: 'views/user/user.html',
        controller: 'UserCtrl'
    })
    .state('index.user.detail', {
        url: '/',
        views: {
            'detail@index' : {
                templateUrl: 'views/user/details.html',
                controller: 'DetailCtrl'
            }
        }
    })
```

In my controller:

```
$state.reload('index.user.detail', {userId: $scope.user._id});
```

Answer (score 0):

As you are using `ui-router` you can use `$state.go('index.user', { userId: {{yourid}} });`

To allow the query string parameter to work using `ui-router` write your state like this,

```
.state('index.user', {
    url: 'user/?userId=:param',
    templateUrl: 'views/user/user.html',
    controller: 'UserCtrl'
})
```

That would allow this to work,

> //http://localhost:9000/#/user/?userId=123456789

Without the query string parameter (your desired URL) would be this,

```
.state('index.user', {
    url: 'user/:userId',
    templateUrl: 'views/user/user.html',
    controller: 'UserCtrl'
})
```

> http://localhost:9000/#/user/123456789

Comment: `$state.go('index.user', { userId: {{yourid}} });` will not load my nested state of `.detail`.  And then if I try `$state.go('index.user.detail', { userId: {{yourid}} });`  I am not reloading the view because angular thinks I'm already on the view I want.  I can't add `{reload: true}` because it will just reload in a loop.  I want to be able to set the URL and reload just the `.details` views